# How to send OOB data on php socket

Tags: php, sockets

I need to send and receive OOB data.

```
   do {
        $result = socket_write($rsServ, $sData, $BUFFER_SIZE);

        if (rand(0, 1)){
            $resultOOB = socket_send($rsServ, "!", 1, MSG_OOB);
            echo "Send OOB data\n";
        }

        if ($result === false) {
            $errormsg = socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
            echo $errormsg."\n";
        }
    }
    while ($result);
```

Receive data:

```
    do {
        if (socket_recv($rsSock, $tmp, 1, MSG_OOB)){
            echo "Receiving OOB data\n";
        }
        $result = socket_read($rsSock, $BUFFER_SIZE);

    } while ($result);
```

But php write me warning message:
PHP Warning:  socket_recv(): unable to read from socket [22]: Invalid argument in /home/andrey/Project/050502_shlapkov/main.php on line 84

How to in php may be defined for coming out-of-band data?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this :

```
socket_recv($rsSock, $tmp, 1, 0)
```

instead of

```
socket_recv($rsSock, $tmp, 1, MSG_OOB)
```

the 4th arguement is int, but `MSG_OOB` you could not define before.